# How to set a $cityError variable properly?

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, post

I'm wondering what can I do to set a `$cityError` variable? I think the problem is because my `$cityError` is under the actual `$cityError` variable but I have to keep the `if` statement under my form `echo`:

```
echo $cityError . 
 '<form action="" method="POST">
    <p>Įvertinkite mėnesio orą </p>
    Miestas: <input type="text" name="cityc"><br /><br />
    Mėnesis: <input type="text" name="month"><br /><br />'; 
    foreach ($weather as $value) {
      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $value . '" value="' . $value . '"> '. ucfirst($value) . '<br />';
    }
    echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="Tęsti">
  </form>';

if (isset($_POST['cityc']) && !empty($_POST['cityc'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['month']) && !empty($_POST['month'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['rain']) || isset($_POST['sunshine']) ||
      isset($_POST['clouds']) || isset($_POST['hail']) ||
      isset($_POST['hail']) || isset($_POST['sleet']) ||
      isset($_POST['snow']) || isset($_POST['wind'])) {
  } else { echo 'Pasirinkite orą!'; }
 }
} else {
  $cityError = 'Įrašykite miestą!';
}
echo 'CIA: ' .$cityError;
```

[Here is my image of the form until submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0xzN.png)

My variable is already set up but I don't want to set it until my form submission.

If I do like this (switching places):

```
if (isset($_POST['cityc']) && !empty($_POST['cityc'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['month']) && !empty($_POST['month'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['rain']) || isset($_POST['sunshine']) ||
      isset($_POST['clouds']) || isset($_POST['hail']) ||
      isset($_POST['hail']) || isset($_POST['sleet']) ||
      isset($_POST['snow']) || isset($_POST['wind'])) {
  } else { echo 'Pasirinkite orą!'; }
 }
} else {
  $cityError = 'Įrašykite miestą!';
}
echo 'CIA: ' .$cityError;

echo $cityError . 
 '<form action="" method="POST">
    <p>Įvertinkite mėnesio orą </p>
    Miestas: <input type="text" name="cityc"><br /><br />
    Mėnesis: <input type="text" name="month"><br /><br />'; 
    foreach ($weather as $value) {
      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $value . '" value="' . $value . '"> '. ucfirst($value) . '<br />';
    }
    echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="Tęsti">
  </form>';
```

[Here is my image of the form until submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3jAv.png)

It just makes 2 sentences even if I don't submit the form. After for submission, nothing changes.

Comment: You don't want to show FORM after submission? Or, what you wanted to do. Please Elaborate.

Comment: This `echo $cityError . '<form action="" method="POST">` seems to be the problem. What you are trying to do there is concatenating some string with the `$cityError` variable huh? If this is the **first ever** occurrence of `$cityError` you are trying to access an undefined variable in a builtin function. Which is the reason for the error.

Comment: I want to show error after form submission. I don't want to show anything until form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the whole error thing in a new if so the check is only done when something has been submitted.

```
if ( ! empty($_POST) ) {
 if (isset($_POST['cityc']) && !empty($_POST['cityc'])) {
   if (isset($_POST['month']) && !empty($_POST['month'])) {
     if (isset($_POST['rain']) || isset($_POST['sunshine']) ||
       isset($_POST['clouds']) || isset($_POST['hail']) ||
       isset($_POST['hail']) || isset($_POST['sleet']) ||
       isset($_POST['snow']) || isset($_POST['wind'])) {
   } else { echo 'Pasirinkite orą!'; }
  }
 } else {
   $cityError = 'Įrašykite miestą!';
 }
 echo 'CIA: ' . $cityError;
}
echo  
 '<form action="" method="POST">
    <p>Įvertinkite mėnesio orą </p>
    Miestas: <input type="text" name="cityc"><br /><br />
    Mėnesis: <input type="text" name="month"><br /><br />'; 
    foreach ($weather as $value) {
      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $value . '" value="' . $value . '"> '. ucfirst($value) . '<br />';
    }
    echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="Tęsti">
  </form>';
```

Comment: In this case too, Error: Undefined Index Will Come.

Comment: I only added the if-loop. Where does it error on undefined index? I am assuming `$weather` is generated elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) Btw, my array is $weather = array('rain', 'sunshine', 'clouds', 'hail', 'sleet', 'snow', 'wind');